# How to count the number of comparisons in a Comparator/Comparable?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, timsort

Suppose I have the following compareTo:

```
public int compareTo(RandomClass o) {
    if (this.value() < o.value()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.value() > o.value()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want to know the exact number of comparisons when I call `Arrays.sort(randomClassArray)`, where `randomClassArray` has 100 objects?

Comment: `this.comparisonCount++;`

Comment: Write a common helper class containing an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) as counter, distribute it to your instances in the array and increment this counter every time a comparison is done.

Comment: http://ideone.com/OzW8dB :)

Answer (score 2):

For me the best approach is to use a **decorator** of type `Comparator` that will count the total of times it is called something like:

```
public class Counter<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private final AtomicInteger counter;
    private final Comparator<T> comparator;

    public Counter(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.counter = new AtomicInteger();
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
        return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
    }

    public int getTotalCalled() {
        return this.counter.get();
    }
}
```

Then you will provide your own `comparator` to it and use [`Arrays.sort(T[], Comparartor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) to sort your array, as next:

```
Counter<SomeClass> counter = new Counter<>(myComparator);
Arrays.sort(randomClassArray, counter);
int totalCalled = counter.getTotalCalled();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the answer given by @Bathsheba, it is mentioned that we might have to increment counter twice for comparisons returning `1` or `0`?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey that you compare twice in those cases is an implementation detail - it's a numeric comparison, and so is basically free. Is it really interesting to know how many numeric comparisons are performed, rather than how many *instances are compared*? Besides which, there are going to be loads of numeric comparisons performed in the sorting algorithm which you aren't counting either.

Comment: I agree with @AndyTurner  it is an implementation detail that you should not consider. Mixing a counter with your comparator implementation is a very bad design that you should clearly avoid for maintainability reason

Answer (score 0):

Consider binding an *atomic* integral type field called `counter`, say to your collection. Set it to zero before your sorting algorithm, then increment it by one (atomically) inside `compareTo`.

It needs to be *atomic* in case your sorting algorithm is parallelised. I'd shy away from making `compareTo` `synchronized` as that will probably ruin the benefit of any parallelisation.

Perhaps it needs to be incremented *twice* for the return values of 1, 0?

Comment: Is `counter` supposed to be incremented in every `if-else` block?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey: That *might* be what you want to do, yes.

Comment: `it needs to be incremented twice for the return values of 1, 0?` What is the reason behind it?

Comment: If you return 1 or 0 then you've made *two* comparisions.

Comment: Suppose I have `this.value() > o.value()` in the first `if`, does that mean I have to increment twice for `-1` and `0`?

Comment: Incrementing twice would conflate two concerns. One is efficiency of the sort algo, the other is efficiency of the comparator. If you need both, maintain two counters so you know number of ops per `compare` call. Also, the real price is the mispredicted branch and not the numeric comparison, and you have no idea when the branch is being mispredicted.

Answer (score 0):

declare a `public static int` variable and increment it in the `compareTo()` method. 
After `Arrays.sort(randomClassArray)` print the variable and reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a global counter.
Below is my code:

> public class ComparatorCount {

```
static int counter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    List<RandomClass> randomClassList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        RandomClass rc = new RandomClass();
        rc.setValue(i + random.nextInt(100));
        randomClassList.add(rc);
    }

    Collections.sort(randomClassList);

    randomClassList.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));

    System.out.println("compare " + counter + " times in total.");
}

static class RandomClass implements Comparable<RandomClass> {

    private int value;

    public int value() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "randomClass : " + value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(RandomClass o) {
        counter++;
        if (this.value() < o.value()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.value() > o.value()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own class implementing `Comparator<RandomClass>` interface:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<RandomClass> {

    private final AtomicInteger counter;

    public CustomComparator() {
        this.counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(RandomClass val1, RandomClass val2) {
        this.counter.incrementAndGet();
        if (val1.value() < val2.value()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (val1.value() > val2.value()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int getNumberOfOperations() {
        return this.counter.intValue();
    }
}
```

Then call `static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` function with the following arguments:

```
CustomComparator comparator = new CustomComparator();
Arrays.sort(randomClassAray, comparator);
System.out.println("Number of operations = " + String.valueOf(comparator.getNumberOfOperations()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class ComparatorCounter<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T> {

    public int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        ++counter;
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

and

```
RandomClass[] array = new RandomClass[9];
// fill array
ComparatorCounter<RandomClass> comp = new ComparatorCounter<>();
Arrays.sort(array, comp);
System.out.println("compare count=" + comp.counter);
```